# Accessing values from an unknown module, delegating to unknown methods

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a [network protocol decoder](https://github.com/jdibling/hacks) for many different protocols.  This application is a command-line application and does not use Rails.

Sample code to illustrate my challenge ([Live Demo](http://ideone.com/8PtXiI)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# define the base protocol handler

module Base
  MSG_HASH = {0x30=>:One,0x31=>:Two,0x32=>:Three}

  class Decoder
    def decode(wire)
      # get the msg type
      msg_type = MSG_HASH[wire]
      # delegate to a handler for that msg type
      send("decode_#{msg_type}_message".to_sym)
    end

    def decode_One_message
      "This was a One message"
    end

    def decode_Two_message
      "This was a Two message"
    end
  end
end

# define a handler for a specialized protocol

module Special
  MSG_HASH = Base::MSG_HASH.merge({0x4a=>:Foo, 0x73=>:Bar})

  class Decoder < Base::Decoder
    def decode_Foo_msg
      "Specialized Foo message"
    end
    def decode_Bar_message
      "Specialized Bar message"
    end
  end
end

# define a handler for another specialized protocol
module AnotherSpecial
  MSG_HASH = Base::MSG_HASH.merge({0x4a=>:Zippity, 0x73=>:DooDaa})

  class Decoder < Base::Decoder
    def decode_Zippity_message
      "Zippity"
    end
    def decode_DooDaa_message
      "DooDaa"
    end
  end
end

# decode the first specialized protocol
puts "Decoding the first protocol"
[0x30, 0x31, 0x4A, 0x73].each do |wire|
  decoder = Special::Decoder.new
  puts "(#{wire}) decoded to '#{decoder.decode(wire)}'"
end

# decode the second specialized protocol
puts "Decoding the second protocol"
[0x30, 0x31, 0x4A, 0x73].each do |wire|
  decoder = AnotherSpecial::Decoder.new
  puts "(#{wire}) decoded to '#{decoder.decode(wire)}'"
end
```

The incorect output is:

```
Decoding the first protocol
(48) decoded to 'This was a One message'
(49) decoded to 'This was a Two message'
./hacks:13:in `decode': undefined method `decode__message' for #<Special::Decoder:0x00000001ccac58> (NoMethodError)
    from ./hacks:59:in `block in <main>'
    from ./hacks:57:in `each'
    from ./hacks:57:in `<main>'
```

But I want it to be:

```
Decoding the first protocol
(48) decoded to 'This was a One message'
(49) decoded to 'This was a Two message'
(74) decoded to 'Specialized Foo message'
(115) decoded to 'Specialized Bar message'
Decoding the second protocol
(48) decoded to 'This was a One message'
(49) decoded to 'This was a Two message'
(74) decoded to 'Zippity'
(115) decoded to 'DooDaa'
```

The basic problem here as I see it is that `Base::Decoder::decode` doesn't know about the extra values added to `Special::MSG_HASH`.  How can it, right?

My basic constraint is that the `Base` module cannot know *anything* about either the specialized protocols, or anything in the modules or classes that handle those specialized protocols.  For example, changing `Base::decoder` to mention either the `Special` or `AnotherSpecial` modules, or anything within them, won't work for me.

How can I solve this problem?

Don't be afraid to rip my code to shreds.  I'm not at all confident that my solution isn't *completely deranged*.

---

If you're wondering about my constraints, let me explain.  I'm writing a decoder for network protocols.  Some of these protocols share common sub-protocols, and within those sub-protocols are fields (like message-type) which could have values defined either by the sub-protocol or by the specialized-protocol.

An example is message type.  The message type field is present on all messages that share the XMT sub-protocol.  Some of the messages identified by the message type are defined in the XMT protocol, and others are defined by the specialized protocol.  Those specialized message types are unique to the specialized protocol, and there might be overlaps.  For example, in the ABC specialized protocol, message type 0x77 might mean `Quote`, while in the XYZ protocol it might mean `Replay`.  So the specialized message types can only be defined by the handler for the specialized protocol.  But message type 0x30 is defined by the XMT protocol, and always means `Heartbeat`.

Comment: "and does not use Rails." – It's so sad that one has to explicitly state this.

Comment: @JörgWMittag:  I've noticed that questions tagged only Ruby are often assumed to have the Rails framework available regardless.  I just wanted to be clear.

Comment: Also, don't be afraid to rip my code to shreds.  I'm not confident that my solution isn't completely *deranged*.

Comment: John, I edited my answer to include some additional suggestions,

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate of [this question](http://i.imgur.com/dOLkgVR.png).  (Link found at John's profile.) John, I met the one with the stratospheric rep. He boasted that he's downvoted more than half a million answers and has not upvoted a single one!  Now that's impressive.

Answer (score 2):

One way to make it work is to move the specialized message hash into the special class and then access it with `self.class::MSG_HASH`.

Here is the full code; it gives the output that you wanted:

```
module Base
  MSG_HASH = {0x30=>:One, 0x31=>:Two, 0x32=>:Three}

  class Decoder
    def decode(wire)
      msg_type = self.class::MSG_HASH[wire]
      send("decode_#{msg_type}_message".to_sym)
    end
    def decode_One_message
      "This was a One message"
    end
    def decode_Two_message
      "This was a Two message"
    end
  end
end

module Special
  class Decoder < Base::Decoder
    MSG_HASH = Base::MSG_HASH.merge({0x4a => :Foo, 0x73 => :Bar})
    def decode_Foo_message
      "Specialized Foo message"
    end
    def decode_Bar_message
      "Specialized Bar message"
    end
  end
end

module AnotherSpecial
  class Decoder < Base::Decoder
    MSG_HASH = Base::MSG_HASH.merge({0x4a => :Zippity, 0x73 => :DooDaa})
    def decode_Zippity_message
      "Zippity"
    end
    def decode_DooDaa_message
      "DooDaa"
    end
  end
end

puts "Decoding the first protocol"
[0x30, 0x31, 0x4A, 0x73].each do |wire|
  decoder = Special::Decoder.new
  puts "(#{wire}) decoded to '#{decoder.decode(wire)}'"
end

puts "Decoding the second protocol"
[0x30, 0x31, 0x4A, 0x73].each do |wire|
  decoder = AnotherSpecial::Decoder.new
  puts "(#{wire}) decoded to '#{decoder.decode(wire)}'"
end
```

Disclaimer: I only tested this in JRuby, not MRI.

Comment: This is effectively what I've ended up doing.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: John, one thing that bothers me about this whole approach is the need to invoke

```
decoder = XX::Decoder.new
```

where `XX` is `Special`, `AnotherSpecial`, etc.  From my understanding of the problem, it seems to me that it would be better to be able to add, delete or rename protocol modules without any change to the other code, and to make use of nested classes in decoding a protocol.

I can think of a couple of ways you might do this. The central idea with both is that each protocol handler would have two methods that would be invoked by `Base::Decorder#decode`, namely: `can_decode?(identifier)` would return a truthy, indicating whether it could decode the protocol identified by `identifier`; and `decode(message, other_params)` whose purpose is obvious.

Approach 1

Create a module `Protocols` that contains (possibly by `include`ing) all the protocol handler modules/classes.  Those classes would not necessarily be subclasses of `Base::Decoder`.  Then use [Module#included_modules](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-included_modules) and other methods (see [this](http://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup) and [this](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/ospace.html), for example) to create an array of all the protocol classes in `Base::Decoder`:

```
@protocol_classes
```

which you would initialize

```
@protocol_classes = []
```

and access by including

```
class << self
  attr_reader :protocol_classes
end
```

To decode a message using a protocol identified by `identifier`, `Base::Decoder:decode` would invoke:

```
decoder_class = @protocol_classes.find { |c| c.can_decode?(identifier) }
if decoder_class
  decoder_class.decode(message, other_params)
else
  ...
```

Approach 2

When I saw your question I immediately thought of a technique described by Russ Olsen in his excellent book *Eloquent Ruby* (ch. 20), that relies on the hook [Class#inherited](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited).  The only differences with Approach 1 is that the protocol classes would be subclasses of `Base::Decoder`, as you have now, and you would create the array @protocol_classes by adding the following to `Base::Decorder#decode`:

```
def self.inherited(subclass)
  Decoder.protocol_classes << subclass
end
```

Again, the beauty of both of these approaches is that protocol modules can be added, deleted and renamed with no changes required to the rest of the code.

End of edit.

Would the following work for you?  You'll see that I simply have `Base::Decoder#decode` ask the calling class for the hash to merge with `MSG_HASH`.

```
module Base
  MSG_HASH = {0x30=>:One,0x31=>:Two,0x32=>:Three}

  class Decoder
    def decode(wire)
      h = MSG_HASH.merge(self.class.hash_ext)
      # get the msg type
      msg_type = h[wire]
      # delegate to a handler for that msg type
      send("decode_#{msg_type}_message".to_sym)
    end

    def decode_One_message
      "This was a One message"
    end

    def decode_Two_message
      "This was a Two message"
    end
  end
end
```

Define a handler for a specialized protocol

```
module Special
  MSG_HASH = {0x4a=>:Foo, 0x73=>:Bar}

  class Decoder < Base::Decoder
    def self.hash_ext
      MSG_HASH
    end
    def decode_Foo_message
      "Specialized Foo message"
    end
    def decode_Bar_message
      "Specialized Bar message"
    end
  end
end
```

Define a handler for another specialized protocol

```
module AnotherSpecial
  MSG_HASH = {0x4a=>:Zippity, 0x73=>:DooDaa}

  class Decoder < Base::Decoder
    def self.hash_ext
      MSG_HASH
    end
    def decode_Zippity_message
      "Zippity"
    end
    def decode_DooDaa_message
      "DooDaa"
    end
  end
end
```

Decode the first specialized protocol

```
puts "Decoding the first protocol"
[0x30, 0x31, 0x4A, 0x73].each do |wire|
  decoder = Special::Decoder.new
  puts "(#{wire}) decoded to '#{decoder.decode(wire)}'"
end
(48) decoded to 'This was a One message'
(49) decoded to 'This was a Two message'
(74) decoded to 'Specialized Foo message'
(115) decoded to 'Specialized Bar message'
=> [48, 49, 74, 115]
```

Decode the second specialized protocol

```
puts "Decoding the second protocol"
[0x30, 0x31, 0x4A, 0x73].each do |wire|
  decoder = AnotherSpecial::Decoder.new
  puts "(#{wire}) decoded to '#{decoder.decode(wire)}'"
end

(48) decoded to 'This was a One message'
(49) decoded to 'This was a Two message'
(74) decoded to 'Zippity'
(115) decoded to 'DooDaa'
=> [48, 49, 74, 115]
```

Alternatively, to provide more flexibility, one could replace

```
h = MSG_HASH.merge(self.class.hash_ext)
```

in `Base::Decoder#decode` with

```
h = self.class.hash_ext(MSG_HASH)
```

and replace the class method `hash_ext` in the `Special` and `AnoherSpecial` modules with

```
def self.hash_ext(base_hash)
  base_hash.merge(MSG_HASH)
end
```

or with something else, depending on requirements.

Comment: Just so you know, I'm not ignoring this answer or any of your edits.  It just got me thinking is all.  Would upvote 5 mote times if I could.

Comment: No problem, John, I could hear you thinking.  I wish I could help you with the upvotes, but rules are rules.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the `Special::MSG_HASH` constant and add the following line to your `Special::Decoder` class:

```
Base::MSG_HASH.merge!(0x4a => :Foo, 0x73 => :Bar)
```

Note however that this will modify the `Base::MSG_HASH` constant.

You also have defined `decode_Foo_msg`, you propably wanted to type `decode_Foo_message` instead.

Anyway you should take a look at the [`Forwardable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html) module.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks.  Unfortunately IRL the base decoder will not know *anything* about the specialized protocols.  `Special::Decoder.new` will be impossible there.  I should have listed that as a constraint (I've since edited.)  Can this be re-worked within this new constraint?  Also this looks like it would have potential performance implications.  I'm not too worried about that just now, but it stuck out to me. +1 for the effort.

Comment: Thanks, and take your time.  In the meantime, I'm going to read about `Forwardable`.  I was completely unfamiliar with it until you mentioned it.

Comment: What about now @JohnDibling?

Comment: Thanks again.  Unfortunately I think its pretty clear at this point that I completely *failed* to elaborate adequately on my constraints.  I've just made a significant edit to try to clear it up a bit.  Your first solution won't work for me because it would require the `Base` module to know the internal workings of a specialized protocol's module.  See my updated code for elaboration.  Your second solution just might work though.  It feels like a hack, though.  Is it?

Comment: I would worry first about `Object#send` and then about modifying a constant within from another class. I wouldn't call this a hack. I would call the whole logic a hack though :)

Comment: Is `send` a hack?  Don't assume I'm a Ruby expert.  I'm still a hack myself.  What's a better way to call a method based on a runtime vale without employing a giant `case`? I had thought that `send` was the main approach.

Comment: Re: " I would call the whole logic a hack though "  I would too, but I couldn't think of a better approach.

Comment: None of these is a hack. `send` is generally discouraged though there may be better solutions to this like, mix-ins, delegators, dependency injection etc.